# While Uploading webresource to mobilefirst Server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Cordova application, while uploading web resource zip file to Mobilefirst 8 server giving error cant read the content failed to extract data from zip. Malformed zip file.

Comment: Please add more details

Comment: How did you create the zip file ? As the previous comment says, please add more details to the question to prevent it from being downvoted. Also provide the exact error message you see.

Comment: Created Zip file Using Command Line Mfpdev app webupdate --build and then upload that Zip file to ibm-Mobilefirst 8 Server.Its Mobilefirst 8 and cordova android application.

Answer (score 0):

I tried `mfpdev app webupdate --build` to generate web archive  zip file and successfully able to upload in server.

If you still face this issue run the command `mfpdev app webupdate` this will automatically deployed web resources for you .

For more details read [Creating and deploying updated web resources to MobileFirst Server
Search in all productsUnchecked. To toggle press enter.
Search in this product...](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/t_direct_update_upload.html)